# How to remove quotes from SQL query Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I have the following query:

```
$this->data = \DB::table('months')->select(DB::raw("months.id, COUNT(transactions.id) as total"))
            ->leftJoin('transactions', function($join)
            {
                $join->on('months.id', '=', DB::raw('MONTH(created_at)'))
                    ->on('transactions.doctor_id', '=', $this->user_id);
            })
            ->groupBy('months.id')
            ->get();
```

It involks an error on line `->on('transactions.doctor_id', '=', $this->user_id);`. It added single quotes for variable `$this->user_id`.

How to avoid this eroros:

```
    SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '2' in 
'on clause' (SQL: select months.id, COUNT(clients.id) as total
 from `months` left join `clients` on `months`.`id` = MONTH(created_at) 
and `clients`.`doctor_id` = `2` group by `months`.`id`)
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Added to question

Comment: @ako: please be nice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to use `DB:raw` like this:

```
->on('transactions.doctor_id', '=', DB::raw($this->user_id));
```

Comment: I checked my SQL query in client Mysql witout quotes, it works :) I think problem is in it

Comment: Where do you set condition of joining tables? with complicated condition AND? I mean this in pseudo note: `ON tb1 = tb AND tb2 = value`

Comment: I can not use `where`. It sholud be complicated condition of joining tables. May be set brackets?

Comment: ok, try to use `->on('transactions.doctor_id', '=', (int)$this->user_id);`

Comment: Tried, is the same issues.

Comment: @OPV For joining two tables you just use one pair PK/FK.

Comment: Try this one:  `->on('transactions.doctor_id', '=', DB::raw($this->user_id));`

Comment: Yes, now it is working. Modify your question, I will accept